# Win32Exception when trying to save a file

Tags: winforms, win32exception

I'm developing a `Windows Form` application under Windows XP. I've created a `Class Library` that is accessed by the user application in order to create PDF documents using PdfSharp and MigraDoc libraries.

My problem starts when I try to add a bitmap to the PDF. I have the image stored in the resources, and due MigraDoc features, I firstly need to save the file on the disk in order to do that, as you can see in the next lines:

```
string logoTemp = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\imagename.png";
if (!File.Exists(logoTemp))
  ((Bitmap)Properties.Resources.imagename).Save(logoTemp, ImageFormat.Png);
paragraph.AddImage(logoTemp);
```

It works fine on my computer and also on a 32 bits Windows 7, but it gets throw an exception on 64 bits Windows 7, as showed in the next screenshot:

[image]

This error is solved if I run the application as Administrator, but that is not acceptable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a `try { } catch() {}` block and see what exception it throws using a debugger.

Comment: Install a debugger? I mean VS Express is free, so you could just install that.

Comment: I'll try to print out the catched exception and let you know about it.

Comment: Solved! In a earlier version of the application I tried to store the temporal image in the root of C:\ and it seems that the DLL project who stores such image was not being updated, so the program still tried to store the file in C:\ and that is why I needed Admin privileges. Thanks!